# Writing a dataframe back to BQ table

Tags: python, google-bigquery

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
# job_config.autodetect = True
# job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("Weekend", "INT64")

])
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    full_df_at, table_id, job_config=job_config
)

# Wait for the load job to complete.
job.result()
print('A table {} is created'.format(table_id))
```

This code is resulting in following error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-c4a9bfab1edc> in <module>
      5 
      6 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
----> 7     bigquery.SchemaField("Weekend", "INT64")
      8 
      9 ])

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'schema'
```

How do I resolve it? THis code has been working fine. Is this because of changes to Pandas upgrades? How do I make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
# job_config.autodetect = True
# job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("Weekend", "INT64")
   ]

job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    full_df_at, table_id, job_config=job_config
)

# Wait for the load job to complete.
job.result()
print('A table {} is created'.format(table_id))
```

You can check the [Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/dc389498391798235383fbec20e48a23128ddc6a/docs/snippets.py#L473) where  you can find an example of how to use LoadJobConfig.